# GridView Row Number using Markup (only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a requirement to display row number in grid view. What is the best way to display the row number using BoundField or TemplateField?

Note: This need to be done using markup only (without code behind).

Note: When sorting happens, the row number should not be in sequence, the first row should go down with its content.

I have already referred the following:

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/2eead3e3-5cc2-40f7-a91c-8f7942d5329c/

Comment: can i know is there any specific reason to show row number ? as Row Number is zero based(0,1,2,3...), if you want to show Serial No then you can use `<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#" >
     <ItemTemplate>
     <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

By the way, this solution proposed in article you referred. Why you don't like it and ask here?

Comment: When sorting happens, the row number should not be in sequence, the first row should go down with its content.

Comment: Then you need to have property in datasource object for row index.

Answer (score 4):

The best place to do this would be to use the templatefield

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row Number">
>   <ItemTemplate>
>     <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
>   </ItemTemplate>
> </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

An examples http://www.devcurry.com/2010/01/add-row-number-to-gridview.html

The BoundField displays the value of specified DataSource field as text.
The TemplateField allows to mix html or make use of web controls.

Please refer to the following explanation to confirm the difference.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1804988.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

The gridview is rendered as html table. If you don't want to calculate the row number in code behind, you should use JQuery.

```
var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
```

And you should fill the table footer with rowCount value.

Comment: this not good answer. Please pay attention to previous answer.